# Converting local url file to pdf that can be used in a website

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with a web developer that's using Word Press for a website that take uploads of files (.doc/pdf) and he wanted to do the same in iOS app. I can get access to the file from the applications folder using UIDocument Picker and display the url in a web view. My challenge has been trying to find a way to convert the url to the format(.doc/pdf) required to upload and be seen on the website. I apologize if this has been answered previously. I wasn't having any success with my searches. Any help is greatly appreciated.

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD28A32A-D8D0-4B8A-B64D-C9EE0AB4EBAF/tmp/com.jkit.TestApiServices-Inbox/5_22_15.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alamofire` to upload fileURL   `file:///` is file URL

```
   func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            if let fileURL = urls.first {
               Alamofire.upload(fileURL, to: "YourURL", method: .post, headers: nil)
                .uploadProgress { (progress) in
                }
                .response { (dataResponse) in      
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can parameters be added to upload()

Comment: yes fileURL is your file that you need to upload  file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD28A32A-D8D0-4B8A-B64D-C9EE0AB4EBAF/tmp/com.jkit.TestApiServices-Inbox/5_22_15.pdf